# Bootstrap-table page refresh issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

For example, I used the bootstrap-table pagination. I am now on the fifth page. I have an operation to delete. He is the modal box of bootstrap. If I confirm the deletion, he will send an ajax request. After success, I should refresh My page, when I perform a refresh, the page returns to the first page, which simply does not meet our experience, I hope to find some solutions, thanksenter image description here[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just before you delete, use `$('#table').bootstrapTable('getOptions').pageNumber` to get the current page number. Then after the ajax call completes and data is loaded successfully, set the page number with `$('#table').bootstrapTable('selectPage', {pageNumber})`

Relevant links:

https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/#getoptions
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#methods/select-prev-next-page.html